# Empty Update Panel Controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel, panel

I am working in a project with modalpopupextender, which controls an update panel. I want to empty all the textboxes and put all the dropdownlist & radiobuttonlist to default status. I used below code:

```
PnlAssets.Controls.Clear()
```

But this code empty all the textboxes as well as the dropdownlists and radiobuttonlist, where after that I get an empty lists in the dropdownlists binded in server side. Fyi I am using ASP.NET in browser side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be better alternatives, but here's how I have approached a similar problem.  I have a common web library with an extension module.  In it, I have written a RecursiveControlList function which gives me all of the controls in a given panel, for example.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns a recursive list of controls inside the current control.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="control">The control.</param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Function RecursiveControlList(ByVal control As Control) As Generic.List(Of Control)
        Dim lst As New Generic.List(Of Control)
        Return DoRecursiveControlList(control, lst)
    End Function

    Private Function DoRecursiveControlList(ByVal control As Control, ByVal currentList As Generic.List(Of Control)) As Generic.List(Of Control)
        If Not control Is Nothing Then
            For Each child As Control In control.Controls()
                currentList.Add(child)
                DoRecursiveControlList(child, currentList)
            Next
        End If

        Return currentList
    End Function
```

To clear your controls, you might use something similar to this:

```
    For Each control as System.Web.UI.Control In PnlAssets.RecursiveControlList()
           If control.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
               CType(control, TextBox).Text = String.Empty
           ElseIf control.GetType IS GetType(DropDownList) Then
               CType(control, DropDownList).ClearSelection()
           End If
    Next
```